# Can't disable animation when using Highcharts in polar mode

Tags: animation, highcharts

I'm trying to use highcharts in polar mode.
I want to add a new series after the initial rendering and I'd like to have no animation. So I tried using 
`addSeries with redraw=false and animate=false`, also `redraw with animate=false`, but still the animation happens. Please see:

http://jsfiddle.net/6u73csk0/

how can I disable the animation and jump to the result? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set animation property to false in plotOptions.series object:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        animation: false
    }
}
```

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.animation

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/d_paul/t4Lp7918/